# When I use a terminal or zsh I can't run commands, And this is what appears: /dev/fd/14:18: command not found: compdef

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion, zsh-alias

When I use a terminal or zsh I can't run commands, And this is what appears:

> #   /dev/fd/14:18: command not found: compdef  #

Does anyone know how to reset the terminal to normal mode?

I tried to solve it and the only thing that got my terminal back to normal is the elapsed time, but the problem is not solved because this line keeps repeating again, and then I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this line in .zshrc it's work for me:

autoload compinit
compinit

i find the solution here :
https://github.com/crissxross/dotfiles/commit/b755c6066267e357b16139bea355579eb3bd4af4

Answer (score 0):

I understood what the problem was, I just installed the latest version of Node js, and that's why I had this problem, when I reverted to a previous version it solved the problem

Comment: This isn't really a useful answer, because it's not at all obvious what happened with the new installation to cause the problem. (At the very least, you would want to mention *which* version of Node caused the problem, but unless that's repeatable, I would just delete the question.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation today, and after looking up the information, it was the reason why I installed Angular

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).